# Different voltage sources in parallel with a diode

Tags: homework

I have a simple problem, I got stuck with it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fekS5i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have to plot the voltage drop on resistor R as a function of its value, the V, and r. The diode is ideal.

So I think about this system as two parallel voltage sources: one with a 2V voltage and 2r internal resistance, and another with V voltage, r internal resistance. The diode won't let current flow to the second supply, so there will be no current between them.

My idea was that the voltage of the parallel system output will be the higher supply's voltage: 2V, and it will have an internal resistance of 2r, so it will induce a current in R like 2V/(2r+R). But a simulation showed me different results (I used the http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ simulator applet.)

So, how could I *mathematically* combine two different voltage and internal resistance voltage supplies?

Comment: That depends what you're trying to achieve by combining them.

Comment: "But a simulation showed me different results".. and what would those be?

Comment: You need to check if the diode is on or not by finding the Thevenin voltage across it.

Comment: What make you think that R should depend solely on V and r ?!

Comment: @CroCo it's not dependent on those variables, it will a variable in the voltage-drop function just like them.

Comment: I used 5V voltage sources, 1k internal resistances and a 10k load. The main current according to this simulation is constant 625uA.

Comment: Are you sure the software models the diode as on-off switch?!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the diode is always off if incorrect. Whether the diode is conducting or not depends on the voltage across R.

If r is large and R is small the voltage across R can be less than V minus a diode drop, at which time the ideal diode will turn on. A real diode will conduct some before that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjjcC5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the voltage across R is < (V minus a diode drop), the diode is on.

Knowing that, you should be able to figure out the math that defines that condition for various values of V, R and r.

Comment: Okkay, thanks. Please correct me if I am wrong. So, if the ratio of r and R pulls the voltage on Node A under the (V-diode drop) limit, the V3 source will start to "work", and I should try to use KCLs? Until then, it is "normal operation", and V3 acts like it isn't there?

Comment: @user3853774 correct, for an ideal diode, yes.